# Remember the last viewing settings

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, question-order

The default view for questions you have asked (in your profile) is ordering by votes. Wouldn't it be nice if the system would remember the last viewing settings applied ?

Bill the Lizard is stuck with the john skeet fact question on top of his list. He can change the ordering, but it always comes back.

I also prefer "newest" than "more votes".

Please do something for poor little Billy here, crying for help ;).

P.S. the same applies to other section as well.